# virtual base class and initialization lists

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [gcc c++ virtual inheritance problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126522/gcc-c-virtual-inheritance-problem)

Hi all,

I'm wondering about how the compiler would handle different initialization values when using multiple inheritance from a virtual base class. Consider the notorious 'diamond of dread' inheritance scheme:

```
     Base
     / \
    /   \
  D1     D2
    \   /
     \ /
     Join
```

In order to avoid having two copies of `Base` in `Join`, I use virtual inheritance for `D1` and `D2` (see e.g. [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html)). Now, lets say `Base` is not abstract, but has a member field, which is initialized in its constructor:

```
class Base { 
public:
    Base(int x_) {x = x_;};
    virtual ~Base(){};

public:
    int x;
};

class D1 : public virtual Base {
public:
    D1() : Base(1) {};
    virtual ~D1(){};
};

class D2 : public virtual Base {
public:
    D2() : Base(2) {};
    virtual ~D2(){};
};

class Join : public D1, public D2 {
public:
    Join(){};
    ~Join(){};
};

int main()
{
   Join j;
   cout << j.x << endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Will the output be 1, 2, or is it compiler-dependent?

Comment: No need for new, the test case code is just as valid with `Join j; cout << j.x;`.

Comment: @Charles, this question isn't GCC-specific so it isn't strictly a duplicate. Although it does address the same issue and the answer is compiler-independent.

Comment: @SergeyTachenov: Neither is that question gcc specific, it just happens to have gcc in the title which is a little bit misleading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It shoudn't compile. Virtual bases are initialized by the most derived class which is `Join`. `Join` doesn't explicitly initialize `Base` but `Base` has no accessible default constructor.

[It also won't compiler because definitions of classes need to be terminated with a `;` but I've assumed that this is a typo. `main` should also return `int` and I've assumed that `j.x` is a typo for `j->x`.]

Answer (score 2):

When you have virtual inheritance it is the final class that must initialise the virtual base class.

Therefore the constructor of Join must construct Base:

```
   class Join : public D1, public D2 
    {
    public:
        Join() : Base(3){} // or whatever value
        ~Join(){}
    };
```

It is the exception to the rule that classes only normally initialise their immediate base-classes.

(Aside from that `main` should return `int` and you would need to do `j->x` not `j.x` as j is a pointer, as well as the fact you must `delete` it as you called `new`)

Comment: You beat me to it by 17 secs :D

Answer (score 1):

Since the Base does not have an implicit constructor and both `C1` and `C2` are virtual bases, you would have to change it like this (and also add semicolons after the rest of the class declarations as pointed out by Charles Bailey)

```
class Join : public D1, public D2 {
public:
    Join() : Base(3) {};
    ~Join(){};
};

int main()
{
   Join j;
   cout << j.x << endl;
}
```

Then it would print `3` to the standard output