# undefined reference to, but it is defined

Tags: c++, reference, undefined

I have a class A with virtual inline getters and setters. From A there are two classes B and C derived. And I have a class D, derived from B and C.
Creatung an object from D and using the getName() results in "undefined reference to getName()". Removing "inline" doens't work. The header file is included correctly.
What's the problem here?

```
class A
{
    public:
        virtual inline std::string getName() const{return name;}

    protected:
        std::string name;
};

class B : public virtual A {};
class C : public virtual A {};

class D : public B, public C {};
```

Comment: Do you really want virtual inheritance?

Comment: Paste code that demonstrates the problem. The code above does not show it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [gcc c++ virtual inheritance problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126522/gcc-c-virtual-inheritance-problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compiles fine with/without `inline` : [with inline](http://ideone.com/qKW2K) and [without inline](http://ideone.com/Wtkr6)

But remember this otherwise : in a virtual inheritance, you've to initialize the base explicitly IF the base class constructor takes parameter as,

```
class D : public B, public C 
{
   public:
      D(string s) : A(s), B(s), C(s){}
                  //^^^^ note this!

};
```

Just `D(string s) : B(s), C(s)` would not be enough: http://ideone.com/MPUPj

`A(s)` is *also* needed : http://ideone.com/DNLkA

See this topic for more detail: [about virtual base class and virtual inheritance in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907264/about-virtual-base-class-and-virtual-inheritance-in-c)

Comment: No, you don't have to explicitly initialize the virtual base if it is default-constructible, which in this case it is. No?

Comment: Wouldn't the compiler generate a working default constructor since there is no constructor defined in the code from the question?

Comment: @Armen: You're right. I missed that point. Updated my answer!