# Inheriting constructors of virtual base classes

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, g++, virtual-inheritance

Virtual base classes are initialized in the most derived class, so my guess is that inheriting the constructor of the base class should work as well:

```cpp
struct base {
    base(int) {}
};

struct derived: virtual base {
    using base::base;
};

derived d(0);
```

However, this fails to compile with GCC 5.2.0, which tries to find `base::base()`, but works fine with Clang 3.6.2. Is this a bug in GCC?

Comment: relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126522/c-virtual-inheritance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is gcc bug [58751](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58751)
"*[C++11] Inheriting constructors do not work properly with virtual inheritance*"
(aka: [63339](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63339)
"*using constructors" from virtual bases are implicitly deleted*"):

From the 58751 description:

> In the document N2540 it states that:
>
> Typically, inheriting constructor definitions for classes with virtual bases will be ill-formed, unless the virtual base supports default initialization, or the virtual base is a direct base, and named as the base forwarded-to. Likewise, all data members and other direct bases must support default initialization, or any attempt to use a inheriting constructor will be ill-formed. Note: ill-formed when used, not declared.
>
> Hence, the case of virtual bases is explicitly considered by the committee and thus should be implemented.

Workaround borrowed from the bug report:

```
struct base {
    base() = default;  // <--- add this
    base(int) {}
};
```

According to the bug report, in this cases the constructor `base::base(int)` is called by the implicitly generated constructor `derived::derived(int)`.

I have checked that [your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d44786fc57bde885) does not compile. But [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c49d065932b4ceb3) does and it calls the `base::base(int)` constructor.

Comment: Of course this still doesn't work if `base` cannot be default-constructed... So it appears that the only way around this is manually re-defining the constructors in all derived classes.