# Mixing virtual and non-virtual inheritance of a base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, multiple-inheritance, virtual-inheritance

This is the code:

```
struct Biology
{    
    Biology() { cout << "Biology CTOR" << endl; }
};

struct Human : Biology
{    
    Human() { cout << "Human CTOR" << endl; }
};

struct Animal : virtual Biology
{
    Animal() { cout << "Animal CTOR" << endl; }
};

struct Centaur : Human, Animal
{
    Centaur() { cout << "Centaur CTOR" << endl; }
};

int main()
{   
   Centaur c;

   return 0;
}
```

This code prints:

```
Biology CTOR
Biology CTOR
Human CTOR
Animal CTOR
Centaur CTOR
```

Why?

Since we create a `Centaur` object, we start from building the `Centaur` by constructing `Human`, `Animal` and finally `Centaur` (we start from the less derived to the most derived).

Let's start from `Human`:
`Human` inherits from `Biology`, so we call `Biology`'s constructor first.
Now that `Human`'s base class is constructed, we can finally construct the `Human` itself.
But instead, **`Biology` gets constructed again!**

Why? What's happening behind the scenes?

Please note that it was completely intentional leaving `Animal` inheriting virtually from `Biology` and, at the same time, it was also intentional leaving `Human` non-virtually inheriting from `Biology`.

We are solving the **Dreaded Diamond** in an incorrect way: *both Human and Animal should virtually inherit Biology* to make this work.

I'm just curious.

Also, see this code:

```
struct Biology
{    
    Biology() { cout << "Biology CTOR" << endl; }
};

struct Human : virtual Biology
{
    Human() { cout << "Human CTOR" << endl; }
};

struct Animal : Biology
{    
    Animal() { cout << "Animal CTOR" << endl; }
};

struct Centaur : Human, Animal
{
    Centaur() { cout << "Centaur CTOR" << endl; }
};

int main()
{   
   Centaur c;

   return 0;
}
```

Here we have `Human` inheriting virtually from `Biology`, while `Animal` is set to inherit in the "classic way".

But this time, the output is different:

```
Biology CTOR
Human CTOR
Biology CTOR
Animal CTOR
Centaur CTOR
```

This because `Centaur` inherits **at first** from `Human` and **then** from `Animal`.

Had the order been the inverse, we'd have achieved the same result as before, in the first example - two `Biology` instances being constructed in a row.

What's the logic of this?

Please try to explain your way, I've already checked tons of websites speaking about this. But none seems to satisfy my request.

Comment: What an excellent question!

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It's clear from the output that **two `Biology` objects are instantiated**. That is because you've made **only one** inheritance `virtual`. Two base class instances is the cause of ambiguity in dreaded diamond problem and the solution is to make (as we know) **both** inheritances of `Biology` `virtual`.

Recap of the hierarchy:

```
Biology  Biology
   |       |     # one and only one inheritance virtual
 Human   Animal
    \     /
    Centaur
```

Ok, let's read the output again with these rules in mind:

- Base classes are constructed before derived classes.
- Base classes are constructed in order in which they appear in the *base-specifier-list*.
- **Virtual base classes are constructed before non-virtual ones by the most derived class** - [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126522/c-virtual-inheritance).

1st output - `Animal` `virtual`ly inherits from `Biology`:

```
Biology CTOR     # virtual base class inherited from Animal
Biology CTOR     # non-virtual base class of Human
Human CTOR       # Human itself
Animal CTOR      # Animal's virtual base class already constructed
Centaur CTOR
```

2nd output - `Human` `virtual`ly inherits from `Biology`:

```
Biology CTOR     # virtual base class inherited from Human
Human CTOR       # Human's virtual base class already constructed
Biology CTOR     # non-virtual base class of Animal
Animal CTOR      # Animal itself
Centaur CTOR
```

---

**More informative standard paragraph** (`[class.base.init]/10`)**:**

> In a non-delegating constructor, initialization proceeds in the
>   following order:
>
> — First, and only for the constructor of the most
>   derived class (1.8), virtual base classes are initialized in the order
>   they appear on a depth-first left-to-right traversal of the directed
>   acyclic graph of base classes, where “left-to-right” is the order of
>   appearance of the base classes in the derived class
>   *base-specifier-list*.
>
> — Then, direct base classes are initialized in
>   declaration order as they appear in the *base-specifier-list*
>   (regardless of the order of the *mem-initializers*).
>
> ...

Comment: This answer is gold. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Non virtual inheritance is an exclusive relationship, like membership. A class can be the non-virtual base class of one other class in a given complete object.

This implies that a class can override virtual functions of a non virtual base class without causing conflicts or issues.

A constructor can also initialize non virtual bases reliably.

Only virtual bases can be direct base classes of many indirect bases of a complete object. Because a virtual base class can be shared, overriders can conflict.

A constructor can try to initialize a virtual base subobject in the ctor-init-list, but if the class is further derived, that part of the ctor-init-list will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

1. All the base classes that inherit virtually from `Biology` share one instance of `Biology` base between them.
2. All the base classes that inherit non-virtually from `Biology` have one instance each of `Biology`.

You have one base in each category, therefore you have one instance of `Biology` brought in by `Human` (and in principle shared with others) and one instance brought in by `Animal` (never shared with any other base class).

Comment: Thanks for answering, even though after a year haha